# Search multiple plone site indexes

Tags: plone, zope, plone-4.x

I need to implement a central search for multiple plone sites on different servers/machines.If there is a way to select which sites to search would be a plus but not the primary concern.Few ways I came upon to go about this:

-Export the ZCatalog indexes to an XML file and use a crawler  periodically to get all the XML files so a search can be done on them,but this way does not allow for live searching.

-There is a way to use a common catalog but its not optimal and cannot be implemented on the sites i am working on because of some requirements.

-I read somewhere that they used solr but i need help on how to use it.

But I need a way to use the existing ZCatalog and index and not create another index as i think is the case with using solr due to the extra overheads and the extra index required to be maintained.But will use it if no other solution possible.I am a beginner at searching so please give details as much as possible.

Comment: We use a solr (collective.solr / ftw.solr) cloud to search multiple sites.

Comment: but solr creates its own indexes,right? Is there a way to use the existing ZCTIndex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really look into collective.solr:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.solr/4.1.0

Searching multiple sites is a complex use case and you most likely need a solution that scales. In the end it will require far less effort to go with Solr instead of coming up with your own solution. Solr is build for these kind of requirements.

Comment: Alright..but it says it still does not support full text indexing of various binary formats..i would need indexing of office 2007 and previous formats..is it possible to use external converters with it?

Comment: c.solr supports full text indexing of binary formats. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.solr/4.1.0#indexing-binary-documents There has been some work on Tika as well. I'm not sure about the status though.

Comment: can you tell me which solr version to use with plone 4.2?And also the difference between multicore and single core configurations...

Comment: We are currently using Solr 4.10 on the c.solr buildout: https://github.com/collective/collective.solr/blob/master/buildout.cfg#L12 Solr 5 might be possible. Though, I haven't tested it yet. Multiple cores let you have a single Solr instance with separate configurations and indexes.

Comment: i installed it and  re indexed it which happened successfully according the logs, but the search shows up with nothing  after activating the site search.Can you please tell where is the index used by solr ?and does it use searchable text of the zctindex? as it uses it in the query. And any possible reason why it might not be showing up on search?

Comment: Your solr configuration seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also use [collective.elasticindex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.elasticindex), an extension to index Plone content into [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/), for this.

According to its documentation:

> This doesn’t replace the Plone catalog with ElasticSearch, nor
>   interact with the Plone catalog at all, it merely index content inside
>   ElasticSearch when it is modified or published.
>
> In addition to this, it provides a simple search page called
>   search.html that queries ElasticSearch using Javascript (so Plone is
>   not involved in searching) and propose the same features than the
>   default Plone search page. A search portlet let you redirect people to
>   this new search page as well.

That can be and advantage over collective.solr.

Comment: Querying Solr or ES directly with JS might be a security risk. A user can query any content in Solr/ES, no matter if it might be private in Plone. That's fine as long as you have a public site with no private content at all.